# Add support to large collage to prevent warping and tearing

Tags: material-selection, paper, medium-selection

I had been working on a huge painting made on about 15 separate sheets. After the work was finished I glued together all the paintings, but now after the paint has dried I find that the paper is kind of moist and it tears, curls, and folds very easily.
I want to add a support or something that will keep them safe.
Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Ideas many - but we do not know what to choose for you. Please post a picture of what you have, so we can understand better your situation and needs. The way you describe it (or the way I understand), it is already kind of too late to fix it.

Comment: I am still painting the upper region

Comment: How do you proceed? Collate-then-paint or paint-and-then-collate? Is that paper? (I guess yes...)

Comment: First i painted for about few days

Comment: Then i got really tired doing that so i made some sketches for upper parts

Comment: And then i joint them cause i know that if they wont be there then i will lose then in a few days you know i cant remember where i kept my paintings after few days

Comment: Yes thats paper

Answer (score 2):

Paper has the habit of becoming wavy when wet with water (other liquids too).

So the first thing you might want to try is ti use a non-watery glue, but still suitable for paper.

For the next projects, you might want to investigate about the types of paper available, to choose one more suitable for what you intend to do.

During curing, make sure to apply pressure to the area with the glue - on a flat surface, of course. Worst case, turn a kitchen table up-side-down, place it over the collage, and then add some serious weight over (now inside) it. The floor has to be flat also, or use another table as a support.

Another hint: use a non-stretchable support for the collage, e.g. glass-fiber mesh. You can even build a sandwich: cardboard + glass-fiber mesh + collage (for some added strength).

[image]

Comment: Wow the table idea seems to be a bit heavy

Comment: I did not claim that the table idea is the best, just that it might work ;)

Answer (score 1):

**For your current painting assemblage there is very little you can do**. The paints will have warped the paper, and the glue might have done the same.
You can glue the piece unto hardboard or another rigid surface (using, like virolino mentioned, a non-aqueous glue, such as glue-sticks, like Pritt's - be careful not to get too close to the paints, though, or they might leak), or frame it behind glass.

**For your next project, I suggest using stronger paper**, intended for use with paints, **and taping it to a rigid surface using aquarel tape** (a.k.a. water-activated paper tape - [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9c6OWKyYNKI) is a video explaining the procedure, although I'd like to add that it's best to wait a little with applying the tape after wetting it; it will first shrink, and then loosen up again, and that moment is the right moment to apply it).
After it has dried, you can remove the tape or cut out the paper, and it will be completely flat.